# AABB Swept Collision - Ghost collision on axis

Tags: collision-detection

I have set up a simple AABB physics engine that uses continuous collision detection, here's the algorithm, it's in JS, it's very easy to read for any programmer anyways:

```
var fTime = 0;
var lTime = 1;
var oTime = new Vec();

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var d = "xy".charAt(i);

    if (vel[d] < 0) {
        if (bMax[d] < aMin[d]) return false;
        if (aMax[d] < bMin[d]) fTime = Math.max((aMax[d] - bMin[d]) / vel[d], fTime);
        if (bMax[d] > aMin[d]) {
            oTime[d] = (aMin[d] - bMax[d]) / vel[d];
            lTime = Math.min(oTime[d], lTime);
        }
    } else if (vel[d] > 0) {
        if (bMin[d] > aMax[d]) return false;
        if (bMax[d] < aMin[d]) fTime = Math.max((aMin[d] - bMax[d]) / vel[d], fTime);
        if (aMax[d] > bMin[d]) {
            oTime[d] = (aMax[d] - bMin[d]) / vel[d];
            lTime = Math.min(oTime[d], lTime);
        }
    }

    if (fTime > lTime) return false;
}
```

fTime is the firstTime, lTime the lastTime, oTime the overlapTime on each axis, so I can use it later to calculate the hitNormal. d is the dimension. And vel is obviously the relative velocity.

The problem is shown in this video: https://vid.me/FZwL

As you can see, when the other moving box is created, it collides at the same y axis as the static box, why does this happen and how do I fix it?

In the algorithm, taken from Christer Ericsons book about real time collision detection, it doesn't take care of if the velocity on the axis is 0?

I have tried putting <= and >='s but they will just fail it even more.

What causes these 'ghost collisions' and how do I fix them?

Comment: Did you solve this? How? I just asked a similar question on gamedev. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/115887/how-do-i-deal-with-aabb-sweep-ghost-collisions

Comment: @Nirei Yes, you can have my mail if you want?

Comment: Do you mind putting down an answer with how you did solve it? I am sure that this is a question many people face. It would be quite useful if you put either here or at the GameDev link mentioned above.

Comment: @MAnd Yes I will, I am currently working on it